# Why not ferromagnetic cores enhance electric field?

Tags: electrostatics

A ferromagnetic material can enhance the **magnetic field** passing  through it manifold. But why don't they do the same with an ***electric field***?

***Are there any materials which do so?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ferroelectrics can enhance electric field.

Comment: Can't they be used in capacitors?

Comment: @KRISHNANANDJ : Yes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity#Applications